# error_invalid_expression compile error in a simple boost.spirit example

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost-spirit

I'm trying to get started with boost.spirit on Visual Studio 2013 and I'm getting `error_invalid_expression` compilation errors. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/home/qi.hpp>

void main()
{
  using namespace boost::spirit::qi;

  std::string in("123 234");
  std::cout << parse(in.begin(), in.end(), int_) << '\n';                // works fine
  std::cout << parse(in.begin(), in.end(), int_ << ' ' << int_) << '\n'; // error here
}
```

Here is the template barf:

```
C:\boost\boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/parse.hpp(32): error C2338: error_invalid_expression
          C:\boost\boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp(36) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::spirit::qi::detail::parse_impl<Expr,void>' being compiled
          with
          [
              Expr=boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_> &,boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<const char &>,0>>,2> &,const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_> &>,2>
          ]
          C:\boost\boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp(47) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool boost::spirit::qi::parse<std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,boost::proto::exprns_::expr<Tag,Args,2>>(Iterator &,Iterator,const Expr &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              Tag=boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left
  ,            Args=boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_> &,boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<const char &>,0>>,2> &,const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_> &>
  ,            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>
  ,            Expr=boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_> &,boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<const char &>,0>>,2> &,const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_> &>,2>
          ]
          Spirit.cpp(12) : see reference to function template instantiation 'bool boost::spirit::qi::parse<std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>,boost::proto::exprns_::expr<Tag,Args,2>>(const Iterator &,Iterator,const Expr &)' being compiled
          with
          [
              Tag=boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left
  ,            Args=boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_> &,boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<const char &>,0>>,2> &,const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_> &>
  ,            Iterator=std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>
  ,            Expr=boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_> &,boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<const char &>,0>>,2> &,const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_> &>,2>
          ]
C:\boost\boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp(36): error C2039: 'call' : is not a member of 'boost::spirit::qi::detail::parse_impl<Expr,void>'
          with
          [
              Expr=boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::shift_left,boost::proto::argsns_::list2<const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_> &,boost::proto::exprns_::expr<boost::proto::tagns_::tag::terminal,boost::proto::argsns_::term<const char &>,0>>,2> &,const boost::spirit::terminal<boost::spirit::tag::int_> &>,2>
          ]
C:\boost\boost/spirit/home/qi/parse.hpp(36): error C3861: 'call': identifier not found
```

I tried adding various include files suggested in above lines, but it didn't help. Any ideas what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2):

I used a wrong shift operator when copying an example: `<<` instead of `>>`. It should be:

```
std::cout << parse(in.begin(), in.end(), int_ >> ' ' >> int_) << '\n';
```

Template error messages were helpful as usual :-(

Comment: I don't really see how the error message could have been more helpful? It wasn't even a technical message, but a true Boost Proto generated expression domain assertion. Just start out with /small/ expressions, and build on that. Soon you'll be recognizing your mistakes seeing just the "shape" of the first hundred lines of compiler messages flying by :)

Comment: @sehe Here is one way it could have been more helpful: `invalid operator '<<'` instead of `bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, 'call' identifier not found`. I know that C++ templates are too primitive to produce concise error messages, but I still have the right to complain. It is year 2014 after all.

Comment: Sure go ahead. I was gonna write a response, but [it grew too wide for this margine to contain.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22595782/85371).

Answer (score 0):

@Paul You have all my permission to complain :)

I'm just pointing out that it could be far worse (and it frequently is) and that you could in fact thank the library writers to make this problem traceable at all.

Right now making the jump from "tag::shift_left" to `operator<<` is the only tricky part.

For the rest I'd like to point at the <strike>template barf</strike> evidence:

- the **very first line** reports

  > `C:\boost\boost/spirit/home/qi/detail/parse.hpp(32): error C2338: error_invalid_expression`

  Let's have a look:

  - `error_invalid_expression` tries to tell you you're trying to compile an expression that you shouldn't try to compile.
  - the error originates from `qi/detail/parse.hpp(32)`. This immediately tells you it's in a Boost Spirit Qi expression (and not, e.g. in a Karma expression).

  **Double-clicking** on that first line takes you to this location, which reads:

  ```
  {
      // Report invalid expression error as early as possible.
      // If you got an error_invalid_expression error message here,
      // then the expression (expr) is not a valid spirit qi expression.
      // Did you intend to use the auto_ facilities while forgetting to 
      // #include <boost/spirit/include/qi_auto.hpp>?
      BOOST_SPIRIT_ASSERT_MATCH(qi::domain, Expr); // <-- LINE 32
  };
  ```

I guess what I mean to say is: don't complain, instead just absorb the new ways in which you can "read" the messages. Of course, you're entitled to complain, much like you can complain when at first your nails end up crooked when starting to use a hammer for carpenting.

I just feel compelled to warn that if you can't stomach the message you got in this case, then probably Boost Spirit (or any other Boost Proto, Boost Mpl and perhaps Boost Fusion heavy library) is likely not your thing.

I've had very pleasurable experiences using [Coco/R C++](http://www.ssw.uni-linz.ac.at/Coco/) for parser generating. There are others (flex/bison, ANTLR come to mind). All of the above are well suited for larger grammars and have additional benefits, e.g.

- portability of grammar specifications across different development languages
- tooling that helps in testing/transforming/diagnosing grammars
- vastly reduced compile-times.

I'm saying this as one of the resident [boost-spirit](/questions/tagged/boost-spirit) buffs ([*citation*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/boost-spirit/topusers)).

Pick your tools wisely. And don't cross out personal preference as a factor.

Comment: Nice analysis, thanks. It was my first 15 minutes with boost.spirit and the problem is that I've seen all of the information you describe, I went to the qi source code, but I focused on `forgetting to #include` rather than `not a valid spirit qi expression`. Heavily templated code is out of my comfort zone, but I like the conciseness and tight integration with standard C++ library boost.sprint offers. The cost of it is heavy behind the scenes action, which unfortunately requires the user to get familiar with implementation details. Maybe it will get better with C++17 rewrite ;-)

Comment: It sure will be better. Also, you're absolved. The first 15 minutes are tough. The first 3 months are tricky. Then come the years when you are frequently annoyed by unexpected patches of unproductivity :) Cheers!